# Reducedness is a local property of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to prove that reducedness is a local property, that is, if $A$ is a ring, then:

(i) if $A$ is reduced, then each localization of the form $A_f$ is reduced for every $f \in A$;

(ii) if there exists a set of generators $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ of $A$ such that $A_{f_i}$ is reduced for every $i = 1, \ldots, k$, then $A$ is reduced.

I proved (i). In order to prove (ii), I observed that, for every $a \in A$, if $a^n = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a/1 \in A_{f_i}$ is nilpotent for each $i$. As $A_{f_i}$ is reduced, $a/1 = 0/1$ in each $A_{f_i}$, meaning that there is an $m_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_i^{m_i}a = 0$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, k$. I can take $m > m_i$ for each $i$ such that $f_i^m a = 0$ for each $i$.

What I am missing is a "partition of unity" of the form:
$$ 1 = b_1f_1^m + \cdots + b_kf_k^m. $$
I already know that $1 = a_1f_1 + \cdots + a_kf_k$ for some $(a_1, \ldots, a_k) \in A^k$. How should I proceed?

Comment: For each $i$, $f_i$ is in the radical of the annihilator of $a$, i.e., $f_i \in \sqrt{\operatorname{Ann}(a)}$. So $1\in \sqrt{\operatorname{Ann}(a)}$, which implies $1\in \operatorname{Ann}(a)$. Then $a = 0$.

Comment: @kobe thanks, but I still wish to find that partition of unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $$1 = 1^{mk} = (a_1f_1 + \cdots + a_k f_k)^{mk} = \sum_{i_1 + \cdots + i_k = mk} c_{i_1,\ldots, i_k} f_1^{i_1}\cdots f_k^{i_k}$$ for some $c_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}\in A$. In each summand on the right-hand side, there is a $j$ with $i_j \ge m$ (otherwise, the equation $i_1 + \cdots + i_k = mk$ would not hold). So $1\in (f_1^m,\ldots, f_k^m)$ and we can write $1 = b_1f_1^m + \cdots + b_k f_k^m$ for some $b_i$, as you hoped.